# Populating Monthly cost to daily records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 columns (Date, Flag, cost)
The date starts from the beginning of the year, the flag is either daily or monthly and the cost.

For daily values it is fine. For monthly values, I would like to
Sum the entire monthly flaged values and divide by the number of days in that month. The resulted rate, populate it in the entire month

```
Date      Flag      Cost
1/1/2014        
1/2/2014  DAILY     10
1/3/2014  DAILY     15
1/4/2014  DAILY     56
1/5/2014  DAILY     22
1/6/2014  DAILY     32
1/7/2014        
1/8/2014  MONTHLY   3500
1/9/2014        
1/10/2014
```

Result should be

---

```
Date        Cost
1/1/2014    112.9032258 
1/2/2014    122.9032258 
1/3/2014    127.9032258 
1/4/2014    168.9032258 
1/5/2014    134.9032258 
1/6/2014    144.9032258 
1/7/2014    112.9032258 
1/8/2014    112.9032258 
1/9/2014    112.9032258 
1/10/2014   112.9032258 
          .
          .
          .
1/30/2014   112.9032258 
1/31/2014   112.9032258
```

Comment: The total number of days in a month or just the number of days which appear in the table and having any cost?

Comment: Total number of days in that month, not which appear in the table. If January then it's 31.

Comment: Could you have both daily and monthly values for the same month ?

Comment: The result does not regard monthly values any more after it has split the monthly values to the daily and added them to the current daily cost. For example, 1/2/2014 had a daily cost of 10 and the monthly contribution for that day split is 112.9032258 thus total daily cost is 122.9032258. Hope that answers.

Comment: @szakwani Is the couple (date, flag) unique ? Or could you have several monthly costs for the same month ? Several daily costs for the same day ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yes the Date and Flag are unique dependently.

Comment: Create a row generator for dates, outer join it with your table, and compute the cost. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I understand it well, this should give you the average per day of the "monthly" values:

```
SELECT "Cost" / EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY("Date")) "cost_per_day",
       LAST_DAY("Date") "month"
FROM T
WHERE "Flag" = 'MONTHLY'
```

Once you have that, you final query could be written like:

```
WITH monthly AS (
    SELECT "Cost" / EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY("Date")) "cost_per_day",
           LAST_DAY("Date") "month"
    FROM T
    WHERE "Flag" = 'MONTHLY'
)

SELECT T."Date", NVL("Cost",0) + NVL("cost_per_day",0) "cost"
FROM T FULL JOIN monthly ON LAST_DAY(T."Date") = "month"
WHERE T."Flag" = 'DAILY'
ORDER BY T."Date";
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cea34/14

As about getting "all day in month" this has already been answered several times ([oracle sql query to list all the dates of previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644562/oracle-sql-query-to-list-all-the-dates-of-previous-month), [Generate a range of dates using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418318/generate-a-range-of-dates-using-sql))

Comment: This would result in the average but for one month only, I am looking for a dynamic result which would undertake the coming months. I am also looking to populate in daily basis the result just as the example.

Answer (score 0):

What's about this solution?

```
SELECT THE_DATE, Flag, COST, 
    CASE Flag
    WHEN 'DAILY' THEN COST
    WHEN 'MONTHLY' THEN
        COST/EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(THE_DATE))
    ELSE NULL
    END AS AVG_COST
FROM THE_TABLE;
```

Comment: I would like to populate the split in the respective days of the months.

Answer (score 0):

First let look at the **ROW GENERATOR** to get the list of all dates for the month including the equal number of **buckets for COST** divided equally for each day of the month.

I am hard-coding the value "3500/3" just for the ease of demonstration. In your original query, you just need to join with your table and fetch the **MONTHLY" value from table.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT to_date('01/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date1,
  3      to_date('31/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') date2
  4    FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT TO_CHAR(date1+level-1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') the_date,
  7    3500/31 AS "cost"
  8  FROM data
  9    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2-date1+1
 10  /

THE_DATE         cost
---------- ----------
01/01/2014 112.903226
02/01/2014 112.903226
03/01/2014 112.903226
04/01/2014 112.903226
05/01/2014 112.903226
06/01/2014 112.903226
07/01/2014 112.903226
08/01/2014 112.903226
09/01/2014 112.903226
10/01/2014 112.903226
11/01/2014 112.903226
12/01/2014 112.903226
13/01/2014 112.903226
14/01/2014 112.903226
15/01/2014 112.903226
16/01/2014 112.903226
17/01/2014 112.903226
18/01/2014 112.903226
19/01/2014 112.903226
20/01/2014 112.903226
21/01/2014 112.903226
22/01/2014 112.903226
23/01/2014 112.903226
24/01/2014 112.903226
25/01/2014 112.903226
26/01/2014 112.903226
27/01/2014 112.903226
28/01/2014 112.903226
29/01/2014 112.903226
30/01/2014 112.903226
31/01/2014 112.903226

31 rows selected.

SQL>
```

All you need to do is, add **nvl("cost", 0)** to the **cost** above. You could do an **OUTER JOIN** with your table and add the **nvl("cost", 0)** for those rows having a value for "cost".

Answer (score 0):

This request will do it *only for rows that already* exist in the table

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(D.DAY, 'MM/DD/YYYY') "Date",
       NVL(D.COST, 0) + M.COST / EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(M.DAY)) "Cost"
    FROM SO28292226 D
    JOIN SO28292226 M ON EXTRACT(MONTH FROM M.DAY) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM D.DAY)
    WHERE NVL(D.FLAG, 'DAILY') = 'DAILY'
        AND M.FLAG = 'MONTHLY';
```